# Issue with Text file download in Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I have a download text content functionality in my visualforce page, on clicking which a text file(.txt format) will be downloaded. This file will be created dynamically with the data stored in a Text field of a custom object. Now text file is getting downloaded but as empty file. Here, I am using a JavaScript function(which in turn will call action function to assign file content) on Onclick event. I could notice that my JS function is called after file download. Could somebody please tell me where I am getting wrong?

Javascript fn:

```
function fnDownloadContent(ID, compID)
{
actDnldContent(ID, compID);
}
```

Visualforce code:

```
    <apex:actionfunction name="actDnldContent" action="{!fetchContent}"  reRender="" >
        <apex:param name="Id" value="" assignTo="{!Id}" />
        <apex:param name="compId" value="" assignTo="{!CompId}"/>                                                                     
        </apex:actionfunction>
     <apex:outputLink value="data:text/plain;charset=utf-8;base64,{!getEncodedData}" html-download="description.txt" >
<a ref="javascript:fnDownloadContent('{!lstDet.ID}','{!lstDet.CompId}');">Download</a>
</apex:outputLink>
```

Apex Controller code:

```
public String strContent { get; set; }
public String getEncodedData {get; set;}
public void fetchContent()
{
//Will be assigning text content here         
strContent = 'Hello';
getEncodedData = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(strContent));     
}
```

So far, I could get the required content in a popup window after clicking on download, but it is not downloading any files.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved the issue using the simple javaScript download function. Here the exact flow.

Visualforce Code:

```
<apex:outputLabel onClick="javascript:fnDownloadContent('{!lstDet.ID}','{!lstDet.compId}');" >Download</apex:outputLabel>  
<apex:actionfunction name="actDnldContent" action="{!dnld_Content}" reRender="" oncomplete="javascript:download('{!filename}','{!getData}');">
<apex:param name="Id" value="" assignTo="{!Id}" />
<apex:param name="compId" value="" assignTo="{!CompId}"/>                                                                     
</apex:actionfunction>
```

JavaSript function:

```
function fnDownloadContent(ID, compID)
{
    actDnldContent(ID, compID);         
}  
function download(filename,text) 
{
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);
    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

In the above code, the 'filename' and 'getData' variables will be set on calling the Apex method 'dnld_Content' in the Apex Controller.